# Do you use "take for granted that" without "it"?

Tags: usage

For example, in this sentence

> We took ***it*** for granted that we'd be invited to the party.

Is it acceptable ... without ***it***?

> We took for granted that we'd be invited to the party.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's correct.

The structure is *[ "take" + object + "for granted" ]*. You can also optionally put the object at the end, especially if it's an object longer than about three words.

In the first sentence, "it" is a pronoun between "take" and "for granted". Its referent is "that we'd be invited to the party". This is an example of [it-extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#It-extraposition).

In the second sentence, "that we'd be invited to the party" is the object.

Comment: +1, but I'd also say that the first sentence is actually a version of the second that uses ["it-extraposition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#It-extraposition).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Thanks. I've added that in